# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'et(...)' as it is null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit, next.js13

This error show when I run npm run build **TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'et(...)' as it is null.**
*This is my code * **I think this has something to do with userProtected and AdminProtected, am i getting the state right?**

**This is my store.ts file**

```
"use client"
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { apiSlice } from "./features/api/apiSlice"
import authSlice from "./features/auth/authSlice"

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        auth: authSlice, 
    },
    devTools: false,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware)
});

// call the load user function on query page load
const initializeApp = async () => {
    // await store.dispatch(apiSlice.endpoints.refreshToken.initiate({}, {forceRefetch: true}));

    await store.dispatch(apiSlice.endpoints.loadUser.initiate({}, {forceRefetch: true}));
};

initializeApp();
```

**This is my provider.tsx file where I import the store**

```
import { store } from "../redux/store";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";


interface ProviderProps {
    children?: ReactNode;
}

export function Providers({children}: ProviderProps){
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
}
```

**This is my userprotected.ts file in hooks folder**

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import useAuth from "./userAuth";
import React from "react";

interface ProtectedProps {
   children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function Protected({children}: ProtectedProps) {
   const isAuthenticated = useAuth();

   return isAuthenticated ? children : redirect("/");
}
```

**This is my RootLayout.tsx**

```
"use client"
import './globals.css'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes';
import { Poppins } from 'next/font/google';
import { Josefin_Sans } from 'next/font/google';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { Providers } from './Provider';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLoadUserQuery } from '../redux/features/api/apiSlice';
import Loader from './components/Loader';
import socketIO from "socket.io-client"
const ENDPOINT = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOCKET_SERVER_URI || "";
const socketId = socketIO(ENDPOINT, { transports: ["websocket"] });

const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["400", "500", "600", "700"],
  variable: "--font-Poppins",
});

const josefin = Josefin_Sans({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["400", "500", "600", "700"],
  variable: "--font-Josefin",
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const {isLoading} = useLoadUserQuery({});

  useEffect(() => {
    socketId.on("connection", () => {});
  }, [])
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${poppins.variable} ${josefin.variable} !bg-white dark:bg-gradient-to-b bg-no-repeat dark:from-gray-900 dark:to-black duration-300`}>
        <Providers>
          <SessionProvider>
            <ThemeProvider attribute='class' defaultTheme='system' enableSystem>
              <Custom>{children}</Custom>
              <Toaster position='top-center' reverseOrder={false} />
            </ThemeProvider> 
          </SessionProvider>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

const Custom: React.FC<{children: React.ReactNode}> = ({children}) => {
  const { isLoading } = useLoadUserQuery({});
  return (
    <>
    { isLoading ? <Loader /> : <>{children}</>}
    </>
  )
}
```

*This is my adminProtected.ts file in hooks folder**

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

interface ProtectedProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function AdminProtected({children}: ProtectedProps) {
    const {user} = useSelector((state: any) => state.auth);
    if(user) {
        const isAdmin = user?.role === "admin";
        return isAdmin ? children : redirect("/");
    }
}
```

*I have tried to reslove the issue but I could not*

Comment: let me know the solution if you solve this problem. I have the same problem as you